# Jquery how to use added class from addclass

Tags: jquery, addclass

```
var sum = 0;

$(".selected").on('each', (function() {

        if(!isNaN(this.innerHTML) && this.innerHTML.length!=0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.innerHTML);
        }

    }));

$("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
```

.selected is added class by addclass().
with the other class, the above jquery works, but .selected is not valid one. it just makes 0.00

How can I handle?

```
this.lists = this.tableColumns.children('.list');

//select single list to filter
    self.lists.on('click', '.left-info', function(){
        var list = $(this).parents('.list');
        if( !self.filtering && list.hasClass('selected') ) {
            list.removeClass('selected');           
        } else if( !self.filtering && !list.hasClass('selected') ) {
            list.addClass('selected');  
        }
    });
```

The situation is..
When I click .list, juqery add class(for css) to show the list is selected. 
This is familiar with me, 
but when .selected class is added by the above jquery, I want to sum the value inside .list .selected class.

```
 var sum = 0;

 $(".selected").each(function() {
    if(!isNaN(this.innerHTML) && this.innerHTML.length!=0) {
        sum += parseFloat(this.innerHTML);
    }

});

$("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
```

When I try to sum just .list class, there is no problem. 
But What I want to sum is just for (.list and).selected class, the result looks like that jquery does not recognize .selected class.

I am very very newbie for jquery. I guess I need to order something like .on, but I have no clue.

Comment: Please show your html and full javascript code. Hard to understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

This jquery should work. I just change .on('each') to .each()

```
var sum = 0;

$(".selected").each(function() {
        if(!isNaN(this.innerHTML) && this.innerHTML.length!=0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.innerHTML);
        }

    });

$("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/khristopherallen/8rLy8qh7/1/